# Python directory/module structure and importing

Tags: python, python-module

I'm trying to write a test for my python program, and I've created a `/tests` directory, where `/` means the projects root, **not system root**.

I have all my source files in `/myProjectName`.

Both directories have a `__init__.py` file, but project root does not, and both files are empty (do I need a `__init__.py` in the `tests` directory **?**)

I've tried importing `/myProjectName/main.py` in `/tests/test_main.py`, but it doesn't work.

What is the right way to either structure the project directories or import `main.py` in `test_main.py`**?**

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving your `tests` directory to be inside your project directory.  Then you can use the answers here to import from the parent directory when you're in tests: [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/python-importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Otherwise, you can simply set your `$PYTHONPATH` to point to your project directory when you run tests.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest [nose](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) here as it automatically detects the tests and runs them for you

To run the tests, simply do a

```
$ nosetests
```

in your project directory

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this line in testmain.py:

```
import os
os.chdir("/myProjectName/main.py ")
```

Then execute the script.

Hope it works!